# Can I change the next pointer in a C++ std::list iterator

Tags: c++

I have 2 lists. I want to make the end of the second list to point towards the middle of the first one.

So if you try to traverse the second it will iterate through the second and half the first.

For example

l1={1,2,3}

l2={4,5,6}

I want to make it so that traversing l1 gives {1,2,3}

And traversing l2 gives {4,5,6,2,3}.

Comment: If these are `std::list`, then no, that's not the way `std::list` works.  If they are some other list type, then maybe, depending on how the list type works.

Comment: Just wonder why you want to do this? It sounds to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me

Comment: I want to create a situation where two lists share a common reference. I can easily do this with a custom linked list, yet I was wondering if it was possible to do so with a std::list to avoid reinventing the list.

Also I want to do it to test a function that detects if two lists share a common node.